# Where can I find BR-LE4.0-S2A technical spec. ie, list of UUID for services and characteristics?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, iobluetooth

I am developing an iOS app to communicate with BLE device. I got a BR-LE4.0-S2A device, but I don't know it spec.I only know is once I paired my iPhone with device, I have to write time and an sequence id to BLE device. BLE will start broadcast some data if write is successful. But I not sure to which characteristic (UUID) I have to write these value. If any one  know the characteristic ids or flow how to initiate data broadcast form BLE inform me. That will be great help for me. I am able to connect to the device and read the device name from device.

I am not sure whether I can ask this type of Question in Stack. Stack is the only hope that I have left.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page's tutorial: [The Terminal Program](http://www.byteworks.us/Byte_Works/Blog/Entries/2012/12/28_Build_Your_Own_Bluetooth_low_energy_based_circuits_using_the_Blue_Radios_BR-XB-LE4.0-S2.html).
To my knowledge, there are some predefined services with their particular characteristics. One of them is BRSP (BlueRadios Serial Port) as a serial connection.
Also take a look at the [demo app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nblueterm/id516628472).

Perhaps more documentation is available after a login at BlueRadios' site, but - as they state -

> [...] a proof of purchase along with copy of invoice is required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already checked my device with nBlueTerm app. nBlueTerm app is able to read some data from device. I strongly believe that the developer of nBlueTerm app and manufacturer of our BLE are the same as we can see the company name ‘BlueRadios’ along with both iOS app and BLE device.